# How to Compute the Diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have the problem below here:

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12jLm.png)

> In Exercise 1 and 2 let $T: \Bbb R^{2} \to \Bbb R^{2}$ be the linear operator whose standard matrix $[T]$ is given. Find the matrix $[T]_B$ with respect to the basis $B = \{\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2\}$, and verify that Formula (7) holds for every vector $x$ in $\Bbb R^{2}$.
> $$
> T = \pmatrix{1& -1\\1&1}; \quad \mathbf v_1 = \pmatrix{1\\1}, \quad \mathbf v_2 = \pmatrix{-1\\0}.
> $$

How should i compute this ?

Comment: you are missing context

Comment: Let $E = \{e_1, e_2\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Use the identity $$M_{B}^{B}(T) = M_{E}^{B}(I)M_{E}^{E}(T)M_{B}^{E}(I),$$ where $M_{B_1}^{B_2}(A)$ denotes the matrix representation of linear transformation $A$ with respect to the bases $B_1$ and $B_2$.

Comment: @Jonte Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to address the following. Where did you come across this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jonte At the very least, please tell us what "Formula (7)" refers to so that we can understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

$A:=[v_1\,v_2]$ then $A^{-1}TA=M_B$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
 -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1\\
 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1\\
 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -1\\
 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=M_B$$